# Which of Blake's allies did the abstract demon 'kill'?

Tags: demons, pact

Spoilers for [Conviction 5.6](http://pactwebserial.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/conviction-5-6/)

> Blake realizes that his lighter was destroyed by the demon, because he couldn't remember bringing it, or even ever having it, yet he was able to light the gasoline he had spread on the floor. There is also blood covering the windows, yet we don't know where it's from and Blake doesn't remember bringing any allies.

Who is/was this most likely?

Answer (score 1):

As of today's update - Histories (Arc 5) - Fell sees that

> *The little familiar had taken to the air, circling around a few times, while three maimed goblins with chains around their necks trudged behind, dragging bundles of halogen lights and wires.*

It seems likely that

> The goblins were captured by Blake when he fought the Hyena, or were given to him by Maggie Holt, and their task was to put up some lights in an attempt to bind or scare off the Abstract Demon.